# HQL: left outer join on subquery

Tags: hibernate, hql, subquery, outer-join

Let's assume I have 2 mysql tables:

```
create table tableA (
   id bigint not null auto_increment,
   name varchar(255), 
   primary key (id)
);


create table tableB (
   id bigint not null auto_increment,
   title varchar(255), 
   big_data longtext,
   tableA_id bigint,
   primary key (id)
);
```

And corresponding hibernate entities:

```
public class A {
private String name;
private List<B> list;
}
public class B {
private String title;
private String data;
private A a;
}
```

I have the following SQL:

```
select a.id, count(b.id) 
from tableA as a left outer join 
    (select id, title, tableA_id from tableB) as b on a.id = b.tableA_id 
group by a.id;
```

**How can i convert it to HQL?**

**PLEASE DO NOT OPTIMIZE QUERY!** I'd like to have HQL which will produce exactly this SQL. 
Even if it is not optimal.

Comment: Why is THAT SQL so important? It looks like the result of the query is just A's id property and the number of B's that are in A? In which case you could just do: select a.id, a.list.size from A a which would give you the same result. If you're totally wed to that SQL why not use executeSqlQuery instead?

Comment: Sorry - just noticed how old this is! Nevermind...